# How to make a React Native Flexbox StyleSheet object by reusing code from another object

Tags: javascript, flexbox, react-native

When creating a StyleSheet object in my React Native project, I often want to make a property object that is very similar to another one, with one or two changes.  In the past I just copied the object and changed the name and one or two properties, but I always thought there had to be a better solution that didn't involve copy/pasting.  I thought of maybe extending an object, but wasn't sure how to do it in the context of creating a stylesheet.  I don't know if I'm using the right terminology, so I'll just illustrate with code below.

```
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    titleText: {
        marginLeft: 8,
        marginTop: 0,
        marginBottom: 0,
        alignSelf: "left",
        color: "grey",
        fontSize: 15,
    },
    buttonText: {
        marginLeft: 8,
        marginTop: 0,
        marginBottom: 0,
        alignSelf: "left",
        color: "grey",
        fontSize: 20,
    },
});
```

In this example I want to make buttonText copy from titleText, but just change the fontSize value, in the context of passing in the attributes to the StyleSheet.create() statement.  Is there a better way to do this than writing it all out like above?  I feel like there has to be because as we all know, programmers hate repeating code.

I tried doing something like `buttonText: update(titleText, {$merge: {fontSize: 20}})` using Immutability Helpers, but that gave an "update is not defined" error.

Comment: just merge a default set with a sub-set. look into "merging objects js"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing to keep in mind is that the last property passed will be the one used. Because of that, you could possibly set something up like this:

```
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    titleText: {
        marginLeft: 8,
        marginTop: 0,
        marginBottom: 0,
        alignSelf: "left",
        color: "grey",
        fontSize: 15,
    },
    buttonText: {
        fontSize: 20,
    },
});
```

And use it like this:

```
<Text style={ [styles.titleText, styles.buttonText] } >....</Text>
```

This will inherit all of the styles of titleText, only applying the larger font size.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript has an object inheritance method called `assign` which is part of the Object class. So since `StyleSheet.create` just takes in a regular object, you can use it.

```
let buttonDefaults = {
    marginLeft: 8,
    marginTop: 0,
    marginBottom: 0,
    alignSelf: "left",
    color: "grey",
    fontSize: 15,
}

let styles = StyleSheet.create({

    //titleText simply makes a copy, doesn't change it
    titleText: Object.assign(buttonDefaults, {}),

    //you could also do this and it would work, just not copy the object:
    //titleText: buttonDefaults,

    //buttonText copies the values, and can add new ones or overwrite
    buttonText: Object.assign(buttonDefaults, {
        paddingLeft: 5, //new value 
        fontSize: 20, //overwrite value
    }),
});
```

This way you can even make a default stylesheet elsewhere for your whole app

Comment: This is not correct, Object.assign copies properties from source object to target object, so you are effectively modifying the buttonDefaults. Instead migth be best use ES6 object destructuring and the `...` spread operator to create a new copy of the object: `buttonText: {...buttonDefaults, paddingLeft:5, fontSize:20}`. Furthermore, there is a "React way" of doing the same, see other anwer by @NaderDabit

Comment: Actually yeah, using the solution above I was getting weird results with the  added values overwriting the defaults and I couldn't figure out why until I read your comment (thanks!).  Using the spread operator instead of Object.assign I could get the desired result without overwriting.  I couldn't use the "React way" below because I was using a ternary operator to decide between two style values based on an error flag (`style = {that.state.errors[i] ? styles.errorInput : styles.textInput}`), and I couldn't combine two styles using that operator unfortunately.